# Switch statement ignores Where clause for multiple cases

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Consider the following scenario:

```
enum XYZ {
  case X
  case Y
  case Z
}

let x = XYZ.X

switch x {
case .X, .Y where false:
  println("x or y")
case .Z:
  println("z")
default:
  println("default")
  break
}
```

Even though the `where` clause is `false`, this snippet will print `x or y`.

Haven't found any mention of it. Anyone has an idea how to refactor this without duplicating the code in the first case?

I used `fallthough` for now but the `where` clause is now duplicated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guard `where CONDITION` binds only to `.Y`.

```
case .X where false, .Y where false:
```

Comment: Writing where clause multiple times does not look good. Is there a better way to write this. Maybe something like `case (.X, .Y) where false`?

Comment: Sorry I am no longer into swift. Better adapt existing swift code style.

Answer (score 3):

That's because it matches `.X` case

Basicaly your switch is the same like this:

```
switch x {
case .X:
    println("x or y") // This is true, and that's why it prints 
case  .Y where false:
    println("x or y") // This never gets executed
case .Z:
    println("z")
default:
    println("default")
    break
}
```

To have them in the same `case`, you'll probably have to do something like this:

```
let x = XYZ.X

var condition = false
if x == .X || x == .Y {
    condition = true
}

switch x {
case _ where condition:
    println("x or y")
case .Z:
    println("z")
default:
    println("default")
    break
}
```

Comment: I figured that's what's happening even though the syntax is a bit ambiguous. So how do you create a single case that includes the where for both cases?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you want to do, there are two consecutive cases, so there should be two conditions, and if either one is `true` the block will be executed. Your question is how to merge the two cases into one case?

Answer (score 1):

[The grammer of a `case` label](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID438) is:

> <kbd>case-label</kbd> → `case` <kbd>­case-item-list</kbd> ­`:`­
>   <kbd>case-item-list</kbd> → <kbd>pattern­</kbd> <kbd>guard-clause</kbd><sub>­opt</sub>­ | <kbd>pattern­</kbd> <kbd>guard-clause</kbd><sub>­opt</sub> `­,` <kbd>­case-item-list</kbd>­

We have to write "guard-clause"s for each "pattern"s.

If you want, you can:

```
let condition:Bool = ...

switch x {
case let x where (x == .X || x == .Y) && condition:
    // ...
```

But I don't think this is good.